# C - Reproduce synchronization issue of a global variable between two threads with pthread

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I want to reproduce the issue we should get when using two `threads` which modify a `global variable: solde`. The `first thread` increments the `solde` and the `second` decrements it.

It's clearer with a source code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int solde = 250;

void *threadFunc(void *arg)
{
    if (strcmp(arg, "credit") == 0)
    {
        // increment critical ressource
        printf("[credit-start] solde = %d\n", solde);
        solde = solde + 10000;
        printf("[credit-end] solde = %d\n", solde);
    } else {
        // decrement critical ressource
        printf("[debit-start] solde = %d\n", solde);
        solde = solde - 30;
        printf("[debit-end] solde = %d\n", solde);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    // spawn a thread
    pthread_t threadCredit;
    pthread_t threadDebit;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            pthread_create(&threadCredit, NULL, &threadFunc, "credit");
        else
            pthread_create(&threadDebit, NULL, &threadFunc, "debit");
    }

    pthread_join(threadCredit, NULL);
    pthread_join(threadDebit, NULL);

    printf("[final] solde = %d\n", solde);
    return 0;
}
```

What I get is sometimes:
   `[debit-start] solde = 250`
   `[debit-end] solde = 220 (-30)`
   `[credit-start] solde = 250 // <= I wouldnt get this with mutex`
   `[credit-end] solde = 10220 (+10000)`
   `[final] solde = 10220`

And sometimes:
   `[credit-start] solde = 250`
   `[credit-end] solde = 10250 (+10000)`
   `[debit-start] solde = 250 // <= I wouldnt get this with mutex`
   `[debit-end] solde = 10220 (-30)`
   `[final] solde = 10220`

But, I observe that the `result` is correct, even without using `mutex`. What I'm trying to get is a wrong result like this (where the two `threads` start with the initial value 250):

`[credit-start] solde = 250`
   `[credit-end] solde = 10250 (+10000)`
   `[debit-start] solde = 250`
   `[debit-end] solde = 220 (-30)`
   `[final] solde = 220`

P.S: When I use a `pthread` mutex`around the inner content of`thread function`, the result is more logic:

`[debit-start] solde = 250`
`[debit-end] solde = 220`
`[credit-start] solde = 220`
`[credit-end] solde = 10220`
`[final] solde = 10220`

or:

`[credit-start] solde = 250`
`[credit-end] solde = 10250`
`[debit-start] solde = 10250`
`[debit-end] solde = 10220`
`[final] solde = 10220`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your thread function so it keeps a local copy of the data, and lets the other thread run after taking the copy. That will highlight the problem you are looking for:

```
void *threadFunc(void *arg)
{
    int local_solde = solde;
    sleep(1);
    if (strcmp(arg, "credit") == 0)
    {
        // increment critical ressource
        printf("[credit-start] solde = %d\n", local_solde);
        solde = local_solde + 10000;
        printf("[credit-end] solde = %d\n", solde);
    } else {
        // decrement critical ressource
        printf("[debit-start] solde = %d\n", local_solde);
        solde = local_solde - 30;
        printf("[debit-end] solde = %d\n", solde);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```